# Load new content within loop in Gradio upon button click

Tags: python, gradio

I have a set of conversations, each of a varying number of turns, which I am displaying in Gradio. Given the varying length of the conversations, I'm enumerating through the turns in a given conversation to output each turn on a separate row (formatted using the Markdown element).There is a set of checkboxes that allows the user to label the conversation. I have a submit button that saves the labels and, here's where I'm a bit stuck, loads a new conversation.

The issue I'm facing is that the conversations are of varying length, so when I load a new one (of a different length) the number of markdown elements don't necessary agree. This leads to the error:

```
ValueError: An event handler didn't receive enough output values (needed: 8, received: 3).
Wanted outputs:
[textbox, markdown, markdown, markdown, markdown, markdown, markdown, checkboxgroup]
Received outputs:
[textbox, [markdown, markdown], checkboxgroup]
```

Here's my code so far:

```
import gradio as gr
import random
import json

conversation_data = [
    {
        'conv_id': '8e271b9985994065bec97e2fdc7b4139',
        'transcript': [
            {'speaker': 'Human', 'response': "What kind of noises did dinosaurs make?"},
            {'speaker': 'Assistant',
             'response': "Humans and dinosaurs didn’t live at the same time, so it’s really hard to say."},
            {'speaker': 'Human', 'response': 'yes they did'},
            {'speaker': 'Assistant',
             'response': "to guess, and that would probably require lots of reading and a certain amount of imagination, so we’re not really prepared to do that. "},
            {'speaker': 'Human', 'response': 'you cant read'},
            {'speaker': 'Assistant', 'response': "there’s a lot of stuff humans don’t know"}
        ]
    },
    {
        'conv_id': '4e341c9235194065bec97e2fdc7b4139',
        'transcript': [
            {'speaker': 'Human', 'response': "How much time do you spend with your family?"},
            {'speaker': 'Assistant',
             'response': "Since I am not a person, I am unable to understand the question, I am not sure how to answer it."},
        ]
    },
]

checkbox_choices = ["A", "B", "C"]


def get_conversation():
    conv = random.choice(conversation_data)
    return conv


def submit(*args):
    data = {'conv_id': args[0], 'labels': args[-1]}
    with open(f"./labels/conv_labels", 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

    new_conversation = get_conversation()
    new_conv_id_element = gr.Text(value=new_conversation['conv_id'])
    new_markdown = []
    for new_turn in new_conversation['transcript']:
        new_markdown_block = gr.Markdown(f"""<br>**{new_turn['speaker']}**: {new_turn['response']}""")
        new_markdown.append(new_markdown_block)
    new_checkboxes = gr.CheckboxGroup(choices=checkbox_choices, label="")
    return new_conv_id_element, new_markdown, new_checkboxes


conversation = get_conversation()

with gr.Blocks() as interface:
    conv_id = conversation['conv_id']
    transcript = conversation['transcript']

    markdown = []
    with gr.Column(scale=1, min_width=600):
        for i, turn in enumerate(transcript):
            with gr.Row():
                markdown_block = gr.Markdown(f"""<br>**{turn['speaker']}**: {turn['response']}""")
            markdown.append(markdown_block)
        checkboxes = gr.CheckboxGroup(choices=checkbox_choices, label="")

    submit_button = gr.Button("Submit")

    conv_id_element = gr.Text(value=conv_id, visible=False)
    input_list = [conv_id_element] + markdown + [checkboxes]
    submit_button.click(
        fn=lambda *args: submit(*args),
        inputs=input_list,
        outputs=[conv_id_element, *markdown, checkboxes]
    )

interface.launch()
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The main idea is to create as many markdown blocks as the maximum number of turns in a conversation, and set the ones beyond the number of turns in a given conversation to be invisible. A bit tricky (and probably some unnecessary parts) but here is the code:

```
import gradio as gr
import random
import json

conversation_data = [
    {
        'conv_id': '8e271b9985994065bec97e2fdc7b4139',
        'transcript': [
            {'speaker': 'Human', 'response': "What kind of noises did dinosaurs make?"},
            {'speaker': 'Assistant',
             'response': "Humans and dinosaurs didn’t live at the same time, so it’s really hard to say."},
            {'speaker': 'Human', 'response': 'yes they did'},
            {'speaker': 'Assistant',
             'response': "to guess, and that would probably require lots of reading and a certain amount of imagination, so we’re not really prepared to do that. "},
            {'speaker': 'Human', 'response': 'you cant read'},
            {'speaker': 'Assistant', 'response': "there’s a lot of stuff humans don’t know"}
        ]
    },
    {
        'conv_id': '4e341c9235194065bec97e2fdc7b4139',
        'transcript': [
            {'speaker': 'Human', 'response': "How much time do you spend with your family?"},
            {'speaker': 'Assistant',
             'response': "Since I am not a person, I am unable to understand the question, I am not sure how to answer it."},
        ]
    },
]

max_conversation_length = max([len(conversation['transcript']) for conversation in conversation_data])

checkbox_choices = ["A", "B", "C"]


def get_conversation():
    conv = random.choice(conversation_data)
    return conv


def pad_transcript(transcript, max_length):
    padding_count = max_length - len(transcript)
    if padding_count > 0:
        for _ in range(padding_count):
            transcript.append({'speaker': '', 'response': ''})
    return transcript


def submit(*args):
    conv_id = args[0]
    markdown_blocks = list(args[1:-2])
    labels = args[-2]

    data = {'conv_id': conv_id, 'labels': labels}
    with open(f"./labels/conv_{conv_id}", 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=4)

    new_conversation = get_conversation()
    new_conv_id = new_conversation['conv_id']
    new_transcript = pad_transcript(new_conversation['transcript'], max_conversation_length)

    for i in range(max_conversation_length):
        if new_transcript[i]['speaker'] != '':
            markdown_blocks[i] = gr.Markdown(f"""<br>**{new_transcript[i]['speaker']}**: {new_transcript[i]['response']}""",
                                             visible=True)
        else:
            markdown_blocks[i] = gr.Markdown("", visible=False)

    new_labels = gr.CheckboxGroup(choices=checkbox_choices,
                                  label="",
                                  visible=False)
    conv_len = gr.Number(value=len(new_transcript), visible=False)

    return [new_conv_id] + list(markdown_blocks) + [labels] + [new_labels] + [conv_len]


conversation = get_conversation()

with gr.Blocks() as interface:
    conv_id = conversation['conv_id']
    transcript = conversation['transcript']
    conv_len = gr.Number(value=len(transcript), visible=False)
    padded_transcript = pad_transcript(transcript, max_conversation_length)

    markdown_blocks = [None] * max_conversation_length
    with gr.Column(scale=1, min_width=600):
        for i in range(max_conversation_length):
            markdown_blocks[i] = gr.Markdown(f"""<br>**{padded_transcript[i]['speaker']}**: {padded_transcript[i]['response']}""",
                                         visible=True)
            if i >= conv_len.value:
                markdown_blocks[i].visible = False
        checkboxes = gr.CheckboxGroup(choices=checkbox_choices, label="")

    submit_button = gr.Button("Submit")

    conv_id_element = gr.Text(value=conv_id, visible=False)
    input_list = [conv_id_element] + markdown_blocks + [checkboxes] + [conv_len]
    submit_button.click(
        fn=submit,
        inputs=input_list,
        outputs=[conv_id_element, *markdown_blocks, checkboxes, conv_len]
    )

interface.launch()
```